# Loop until statement is true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python script to check the status of udp port 5900 on my linux pc and alert me when a connection is established.

I have been able to get the info I need from the os, but struggling with a reasonable way to perform a loop until the established connection is detected.

```py
import os

stream = os.popen("ss -lu '( sport = 5900 )'")

output = stream.read()
```

I would like to run a loop until the connection is present and then print "connection detected". I am new to python so please excuse me if I have missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try implementing an infinite loop until a connection is detected. When a connection is detected, you can print the message you want to and break out of the loop. Something like this:

`while True:
    if connection_detected:
        print("Connection Detected")
        break`

Or if you want to keep checking for another connection even after a connection is detected, you can skip the break statement in the last line.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom watchdog using `while True` infinite loop. In which you can check the output in each iteration of the loop and if the output contains expected string then break the loop.

Also this kind of infinite loop can go for longer time, so you can add a timer as well if you want. In this case, your program waits for one of the conditions, either your expected output or your timeout. see below example.

```
import time
import os

cmd = "ss -lu '( sport = 5900 )'"

timeout = time.time() + 60 # added 60 seconds to current time

while True:
    stream = os.popen(cmd).read()
    if 'connection detected' in stream:  # check your expected string in stream
        print('Connection detected breaking loop')
        break
    if time.time() > timeout:  # checking for timeout
        print('Timeout Occur')
        break
```